# Find headwater polygons

Tags: postgis, postgresql, query, hydrology, rivers

This is a follow up question to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131806/find-start-of-river).

I have a river network (multiline) and some drainage polygons (see picture below). My goal is to select only the headwater polygons (green).

[image]

With [John's solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131806/find-start-of-river) I can easily extract the river start points (stars).
However, I can have situations (red polygon) where I have startpoints in a polygon, but the polygon is not a headwater polygon, because it is flown though by the river. I only want the headwater polygons.

I tried to select them by counting the number of intersection between polygons and rivers (rationale: a headwater polygon should have only 1 intersection with the river)

```
SELECT 
    polyg.*
FROM 
    polyg, start_points, stream
WHERE 
    st_contains(polyg.geom, start_points.geom)
    AND ST_Npoints(ST_Intersection(poly.geom, stream.geom)) = 1
```

, where *poylg* are the poylgons, *start_points* from johns answer and *stream* is my river network.

However, this take forever and i did not run it:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..20547115.26 rows=641247 width=3075)"
"  Join Filter: _st_contains(ezg.geom, start_points.geom)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..20264906.12 rows=327276 width=3075)"
"        Join Filter: (st_npoints(st_intersection(ezg.geom, rivers.geom)) = 1)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on ezg_2500km2_31467 ezg  (cost=0.00..2161.52 rows=1648 width=3075)"
"              Filter: ((st_area(geom) / 1000000::double precision) < 100::double precision)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..6364.77 rows=39718 width=318)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on stream_typ rivers  (cost=0.00..4498.18 rows=39718 width=318)"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_river_starts on river_starts start_points  (cost=0.00..0.60 rows=1 width=32)"
"        Index Cond: (ezg.geom && geom)"
```

So my question is: How can I efficiently query headwater polygons?

**Update:**
I added some sample data to my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1a9as4emg0u5051/sample_data.zip?dl=0). Data is from south-west Germany. It's two shape files - one with streams and one with polygons.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you want the polygons that only contain start points, not the start points themselves. And the start points are defined as in your previous question (which I answered, and as far as I know), correctly?

Comment: Jupp, just the polygons that contain start points AND are not passed by a river / are only starts of the river. The red polygon above contains startpoints, but is NOT a headwater polygon as the river flows through it / does not start within the polygon...

Comment: So, you want the set of `polygons` that contain only those points that are river sources (from the previous question) and to exclude any where two rivers meet. Sorry, for all the questions, just want to be sure.

Comment: No, e.g. in the lower green polygon also two rivers meet. I want to exclude those `polygons` that have a river passing by (the river enters and leaves the polygon) and keep those with starts (and rivers leave only this polygon).

Comment: Right, I have finally got it. Sorry for being so dense. I will think about the solution, and hopefully post tomorrow am.

Comment: Thank you John for your help! All the solutions that I came up with are either wrong or take forever. Perhaps I have to think in another direction...

Comment: How big is your river network, as a matter of interest, ie, number of rows?

Comment: It covers Germany and has ~40.000 rows.

Comment: Would it be possible to supply a small subset of the data? I believe I know how to proceed, but it would be good to test the runtime/query on actual data.

Comment: Yeah, will upload a reproducible data set this evening.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @JohnBarça! I am currently too busy with other things... Will try to provide example data by the end of the week.

Comment: No worries, I am also very busy. But it is a cool question, and I think I have figured it out, so later this week is fine.

Comment: @JohnBarça I put sample data on my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1a9as4emg0u5051/sample_data.zip?dl=0). Data is from south-west Germany and approx. 10% of my data set. It's two shape files - one with streams and one with polygons.

Comment: Great. I'm really busy the next couple of days, but I look forward to it.

Comment: I don't know any PostGIS, so I can't help with direct code, however, in ArcGIS, I'd go along these lines: (1) intersect between lines and polygons into a point file. (2) delete (spatially) identical points. (3) add a numeric field to the point parameter with the value of 1 for every point. (4) spatial join the polygon onto the points and using the sum of the numeric field to indicate type of drainage. A sum of 1 means it is a headland. Higher than 1 means that there are more than 1 entrance or exit.

Comment: My thought was pretty much the same as @MikkelLydholmRasmussen, though I don't know step 3 is required. Spatial joining with a one-to-many should result in a joint_count field, which could be used in place of the summing of the added field. If duplicate points are eliminated first and the match option is intersect, only headwaters should have a join count of 1 - everything else will be 2 or more. In theory you don't even need to delete duplicates - headwaters will be 2, and everything else would be 4 or more.

Comment: I tried without removing duplicates, @ChrisW and it doesn't go quite as well as one would hope, due to the way the polygons fit together. I had headwaters with counts as high as 6.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughts! I am getting closer (e.g. [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66253/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-of-polygon-geometry-and-multilinestring-geome) is part (1) of @MikkelLydholmRasmussen suggestions).

Comment: Cool dataset. I have downloaded it. I suspect this is going to require a recursive query, as it isn't enough just to find places where rivers meet inside a polygon, you have to go back to where all those river junctions have a source and determine if they are within the current polygon or not.

Comment: @MikkelLydholmRasmussen I suspected there might be some issues depending on how the geometry was actually drawn (for example what if three rivers met at a point on the boundary rather than a point just *before* the boundary). Such a case might even be visible in the example image.

Comment: @JohnBarça. It's not a part of my actual data set, but very similar and freely available [here](http://udo.lubw.baden-wuerttemberg.de/public/p/2Z1F).

Comment: This does not answer your problem but comments on the underlying structure. One thing to think about is how your headwater polys are identified. It doesn't seem to relate to stream order. One green poly could be divided into 2 headwaters and the red poly could be divided into 2 headwaters and one other catchment. Is there a rigorous criterion or were they based on expert knowledge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the general outline (partly tested so far) is:

1. Find the points representing stream sources, as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131806/find-start-of-river).
2. Intersect with the polygons table to get a count of source vertices by polygon.
3. Use [ST_DumpPoints](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) in conjunction with group by geometry to get a count of each point. The idea being to get a count of how many rivers meet at a given point.

An example of such a query:

```
SELECT count(geom), ST_AsText(geom) as wkt
FROM 
   (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(foo.geom)).geom 
   FROM 
     (SELECT 
        ST_Collect(ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(10,10)),
                   ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(0,0), ST_MakePoint(20,20))
        ) as geom
     ) foo 
 ) bar 
 GROUP BY geom;
```

which returns:

```
count  |  wkt      
-------+--------------
 2     | POINT(0 0)
 1     | POINT(10 10)
 1     | POINT(20 20)
```

4. Run an intersects of `3` against the polygon table, to get a count (sum of vertices) of river junctions per polygon.
5. Join the polygons from `2` on `4`, rejecting those where the count (sum of vertices) of points at a junction is greater than the sum of the river sources, obtained by summing the sources by polygon from steps 1 and 2. If this condition holds, it means that at least one of the rivers meeting at a junction, originated outside of the polygon in question.

These can all be combined together in a largish sequence of CTEs, unless some tables were created from the steps involving points (and indexed).

I have no idea what the runtime of this will be on a full data set, having only tested part of this on a subset, but with a spatial index on the polygons table, there will be some assistance -- it is obviously not possible to apply an index to the points that emerge from ST_DumpPoints, so a full scan will be required there, although they should be in memory by then.

**This is not being posted as a full answer**, but as a work in progress, and a chance to find flaws in the logic. Working queries coming soon.

**EDIT 1**

This is the query I came up with, which appears to work on a small subset of your data, but runs for hours on the full dataset.

```
CREATE TABLE good_polys as  
   WITH 
     rivers as 
       (SELECT (ST_DUMP(ST_LineMerge(geom))).geom as geom FROM streams),
     start_points as
       (SELECT ST_StartPoint(geom) as geom FROM rivers),
     end_points as 
        (SELECT ST_EndPoint(geom) as geom FROM rivers),
     junctions as 
        (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom 
        FROM (SELECT geom FROM streams) s),
     source_polygons as 
        (SELECT 
            count(rivers.geom) as source_count, 
            polygons.geom, 
            polygons.gid 
         FROM rivers, polygons
         WHERE st_intersects(polygons.geom, rivers.geom) 
         GROUP BY polygons.geom, polygons.gid),
     junction_polygons as 
        (SELECT 
            count(junctions.geom) as junction_count, 
            polygons.geom, 
            polygons.gid 
         FROM junctions, polygons
         WHERE st_intersects(polygons.geom, junctions.geom) 
         GROUP BY polygons.geom, polygons.gid)
    SELECT 
       jp.gid 
    FROM 
       junction_polygons jp, source_polygons sp 
    WHERE ST_Equals(jp.geom, sp.geom) 
    AND junction_count <= source_count;
```

**EDIT 2**. While this appears to produce correct answers on a small subset, the run time on the full dataset is **horrible**, presumably because the final query is doing n^2 comparisons and not using a spatial index. Probable solution would be to break query down and create tables from the initial points and point in polygon queries, which can then be spatially indexed before the final step.

Comment: The query is currently running on my desktop. I have no idea how long it will take or if it will be correct, though it looked reasonable from a small sample of your data. Do you have any idea how many of the polygons meet your criteria?

Comment: I will run the query on a server. I think that only a minor part of the polygons will meet the selection criteria...

Comment: That is what I found on a subset.  I will post my query once it finishes

Comment: Simplification tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, very busy today. I think the answer is to run the source query and the river junctions queries first, intersect with the polygons table to get counts per polygon, save these as tables, and then index them. Then run the final step, where the geometries are equal, and comparing the point count from the two tables. I am hoping this will then use an index rather than doing n² comparisons as present. Will post back later.

Comment: Sorry, still not done. I will get to it, it is an interesting problem. If you could give me the coordinates of a polygon that is a correct source, it would be very helpful for verification purposes.

Comment: I just selected a few polygons in the north of the data set [overview](http://postimg.org/image/cpyp3b1s7/), 
[detail](http://postimg.org/image/4vy3hwtzb/).

Comment: EDi, just so you know, I'm still looking at this. Been insanely busy, but I am very interested in finding a fast and correct answer. Thanks for the screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, this should work:

- select all from polygons
- (FULL OUTER?) join with points on polygon intersects points
- (FULL OUTER?) join lines where polygon intersects lines
- were line.riverid doesn't equal point.riverid
- group by polygonid
- count (pointid) > 0

I'm not really sure how to build the query, and I can't test it without a database to test on. It's a pretty crazy query, I think. But it should work!